# How to combine two lists<Class> without duplicates in one of variables

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list

I have two lists:

```
public class ListTemplate
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public List<ListTemplate> List1 = new List<ListTemplate>();
public List<ListTemplate> List2 = new List<ListTemplate>();
```

List 1:

```
ID = 1, Title = "a"
ID = 2, Title = "b"
ID = 3, Title = "c"
ID = 4, Title = "d"
```

List 2:

```
ID = 3, Title = "c"
ID = 4, Title = "ab"
ID = 5, Title = "a"
ID = 6, Title = "a"
```

And I want to get result:

```
ID = 1, Title = "a"
ID = 2, Title = "b"
ID = 3, Title = "c"
ID = 4, Title = "ab"
ID = 5, Title = "a"
ID = 6, Title = "a"
```

We see, title item was replaced using item from list2.

Propably the best way to get such a result will be used LINQ. Does someone know a hot way to do this?

Comment: Where is `ID = 4, Title = "d"`?

Comment: Is replaced by string in list 2, because they have the same ID

Comment: Your requirement is incomplete. What you want to take if both contains the ID, the item from the second list? Do you want a "full-outer-join" of both lists? What if both lists contain multiple items with the same ID?

Comment: That will be impossible, both lists can have the same ID, but in single list ID is unique.

Comment: Can you answer all my questions please?

Comment: Yes, i want to full outer join of both list, with someting like update using list 2

Comment: My suggestion is to do it without lambda expression. Standard C# code (in this case) is more readable, more maintainable and you can also boost performance using hashsets, dictionaries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have omitted `ID = 4, Title = "d"` from the first list i assume that you want to take all items from list1 + list2 and if an ID exists in both lists take the one from the second list.

Then this approach using `Except` + `Concat` works:

```
var idOnlyList1 = List1.Select(x => x.Id).Except(List2.Select(x => x.Id));
var templates1 = from id in idOnlyList1 join lt1 in List1 on id equals lt1.Id select lt1;
List<ListTemplate> result = templates1.Concat(List2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the lists, group on the id and if then pick the last item from the group (if multiple matches it will be the item from list2).

```
var q = list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Last());
```